# getting bad credentials error in GitHub API

Tags: python, github-api

I am using github api to fetch public info of the users using python but after few api calls
I am getting this error.

```
{'message': 'Bad credentials', 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/rest'}
```

my code

```
token = os.getenv('GITHUB_TOKEN', '------some token ------------')
params = {}
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'}
data = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/' +
                    username, headers=headers, params=params)
data = data.json()
print(data)
```

I am using personal access token for this application with no expiry date.
can any one tell me how to fix this error and give me steps to fix this.

Comment: I ran your code , its working fine for me. Make sure you have `GITHUB_TOKEN` in your env. 
Also pass github_username in  `username`

Comment: @JohnByro after few calls it stopped working for me previously it was working and yes i have passed username  so that's not the problem and what is meaning of GITHUB_TOKEN in your env and can i write it normally like ``` token  = "some token" ```

Comment: I am using my personal token for GITHUB_TOKEN. You might create new token and check the options as needed

Comment: @JohnByro yes i tried to create a new token but after few calls it stopped and started giving this error

Comment: `os.getenv('GITHUB_TOKEN', input_your_token_here)`

Comment: @JohnByro yah i know it but getting bad credentials error. it is working for few calls but than stared getting Bad credentials.

Comment: Then you might need to consider permissions while creating token. Select all check_boxes and try then. I ran it for 150 calls in a loop...all worked fine.

Comment: @JohnByro I got why it is causing the error actually i committed the code on GitHub so GitHub blocked my token.  Is there any way to prevent this